# Install package without internet: error in install.packages: no such file or directory

Tags: r, install.packages, readr

I'm trying to install the [readr package in R](https://github.com/hadley/readr) on a laptop without internet connection using the `install.packages("C:/Users/MVC/Desktop/readr-master.zip", repos=NULL)` command, but I keep getting the same error:

```
error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.0/library/file27f07de57168
/readr-master/R/POSIXct.R': No such file or directory
```

Anybody who know why this is or how I can install the package without an internet connection?

Comment: I updated the path I used

Comment: The tarball you downloaded is not a built version of the package. You will need a toolchain to finish the job. Or ask someone to provide you with a built package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is available as tar.gz or .zip file from cran
download it to your directory.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readr/index.html
and this should work. It worked for me

```
    install.packages("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.0/library/readr_0.2.2.zip",
    repos = NULL, type="source")
```

Please make sure that the path is correct.

Comment: having packages on Desktop not a good idea. Find the updated answer

Comment: Thanks but that of course requires me to install the devtools package which again gives the same error message, i.e. "no such file or directory"

Comment: Check the update. It worked for me. Can you update your Q with the complete error / warnings it throws when you run ?